# How to implement user based parameter visibility toggle in Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a repo for my Jenkins pipeline, I maintain one branch for the build pipeline (I don't want to have separate branches for devs/QAs/Prod). I want to use this single branch to create single Jenkins pipeline for all Devs/QA/Prod. Based on the the type of user, I want to change the build agent, where the pipeline runs. For example:

- For build triggered by Devs: agent should be build-server 1 (This should be enforced)
- For build triggered by QA: agent should be build-server 2 (This should be enforced)
- For build triggered by Prod: agent should be build-server 1,2 or 3 (User can use any agent)

For Devs/QAs I don't want them to see the option to change the build agent parameter, in this case it should enforced or passed in some hidden way. But for Prod, I want to give option to choose any of the build agent out of three. Anyone who is implemented such case, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain a list of Devs, QAs and Prods and then you can use Active Choice Parameter with below groovy script:

```
import hudson.model.User
def Devs = ['Dev1_email', 'Dev2_email']
def QA = ['qa1_email', 'qa2_email']
def Prod = ['prod1_email', 'prod2_email']
def user = User.current()

if(Devs.contains(user.toString())){
    return ['build-server 1']
}
else if(QA.contains(user.toString())){
    return ['build-server 2']
}
else if(Prod.contains(user.toString())){
    return ['build-server 1', 'build-server 2', 'build-server 3']
}
```